# WPF - MVVM - How to update notify combobox of propertychange

Tags: c#, wpf

I am entirely new to WPF and the implementation of MVVM Pattern, therefore excuse me if what I did so far can be seen close to blasphemy in certain people's eyes.

My (partial) goal as it follows:

1. Open main window which contains two Comboboxes labeled System and Documents
2. Upon loading this window I connect to an .accdb file that contains a table with System and Document columns.
3. It creates a list of all the distinct System names stored in the database file and stores them as an arrayList to which my "System" combobox is bound to. It successfully fills up the combobox and chooses the first member of the list as a selected item.
4. The selectedItem of the "System" combobow is OneWayToSource bound to a string called SystemFilter. Anytime I changed hte selection this string is succesfully updated.
5. PROBLEMATIC PART: I also want to filter out the documents belonging to the selected system and fill up the "Document" combobox. The helper method I wrote successfully does it using the SystemFilter string, and created an arrayList with the list of the Documents. However the "Document" Combobox is not updated even though it is bound to this arrayList. The interesting thing that sometimes if I run this helper method with a hardwired String argument it correctly updates the combobox.

My MainWindow.xaml (relevant part):

```
            <!--System-->
            <TextBlock Margin="5 0 0 0" Text="System" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <ComboBox SelectionChanged="Combobox_Doc_Sys_SelectionChanged" x:Name="Combobox_Doc_Sys" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding mSystemList}" SelectedItem="{Binding mSystemFilter,Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                      SelectedIndex="0" Padding="2" Margin="5 0 5 0" >
            </ComboBox>

            <!--Document-->
            <TextBlock Margin="5 10 0 0" Text="Document" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="Combobox_Doc_Doc" ItemsSource="{Binding mTitleList}" SelectedIndex="0" 
                      Padding="2" Margin="5 0 5 0">
            </ComboBox>
```

The code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
     }

    private void Combobox_Doc_Sys_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindowViewModel.GetListOfTitle();
    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel:

```
class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

    static ArrayList SystemList = new ArrayList();
    public static ArrayList mSystemList { get { return SystemList; } set { } }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    static ArrayList TitleList = new ArrayList();
    public static ArrayList mTitleList { get { return TitleList; } set { } }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    static ArrayList RevisionList = new ArrayList();
    public static ArrayList mRevisionList { get { return RevisionList; } set{ } }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    public static ObservableCollection<DocumentModel> DocumentList = new ObservableCollection<DocumentModel>();
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    static string SystemFilter = String.Empty;
    public static string mSystemFilter{get { return SystemFilter; } set { SystemFilter = value; } }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    static readonly string ConnectStringDocList = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Model\\Data\\DocumentList.mdb";

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        GetListofSystems();
        GetListOfTitle();

    }
    public static void GetListofSystems()
    {


        //SQL for gettint all the distinctive values from the system column
        string listSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT System FROM DocList";

        SystemList.Clear();

        //Creating new connection
        using (OleDbConnection MyConnection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectStringDocList))
        {
            //Create command
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(listSQL, MyConnection);
            command.Connection = MyConnection;
            MyConnection.Open();
            //Create reader
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            //With given parameter "listSQL" we iterate through the "system" column of DocumentList.mdb
            // and wee fill up "SystemList" with all the distinctive values

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string item = reader.GetString(0);
                SystemList.Add(item);
            }

            //Close reader
            reader.Close();
            //Close connection
            MyConnection.Close();

        }
    }

    public static void GetListOfTitle()
    {
        //List that will store the list of the title

        //filtering  SQL
        string sysFilterSQL = $"SELECT * FROM DocList WHERE System='{SystemFilter}'";

        //Clear List for safety sake
        TitleList.Clear();

        using (OleDbConnection MyConnection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectStringDocList))
        {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sysFilterSQL, MyConnection);
            command.Connection = MyConnection;
            MyConnection.Open();

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            //We fill up TitleList with the list of the titles filtered by "system"
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var item = reader.GetString(2);
                TitleList.Add(item);
            }
                        }

    }
```

And the BaseViewModel:

```
    public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The event that is fired when any child poperty changes its value
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = ( sender, e) =>{ };

}
```

Thank you for the answers in advance. I was trying to find a clear straightforward tutorial on this but no success. How do I notify properly my UI that the source has changed...

Answer (score 0):

You want to change something in the ViewModel and it should update the view. This only works by using Notify**Property**Changed for properties and INotify**Collection**Changed for collections. In your case, just use `ObservableCollection<string>`, it has already both implemented.

```
public ObservableCollection<string> TitleList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

Use `TitleList` as your `ItemSource` in the view instead of `mTitleList`. And add stuff directly to it in the ViewModel like that (I am not 100% sure with the syntax, you have to try out or google it)

```
TitleList.Add("my stuff");
```

Some additonal notes

1. for me it is quite hard to read your code, because I am not used with the nameing convention you are using. If you are allowed at work, switch to microsoft c# naming convention: Property names in PascalCase (TitleList) and field names camelcase with _-prefix (_titleList).
2. First time I see `ArrayList` being used. If you have a certain reason for this, keep it. But usually we use `List<string>` for everything that would be a string array in other languages.
3. your BaseViewModel is insufficient. In the future you may want to be able to raise the PropertyChanged event in your ViewModel with a property name in the EventArgs. Important Note: you fire the PropertyChanged event in your ViewModel. Noone else does that. The view (or rather the binding class) subscribes to the PropertyChange Event of your ViewModel with an eventHandler, so that it is notified, when you raise the PropertyChanged event in your ViewModel [Some more information about it](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=netframework-4.8)
4. should those fields be backing fields for the properties? if yes, then you made them wrong. This is how it is done:

```
private string _myText;

public bool MyText
{
   get => _myText;
   set { _myText = value; // raise notify property changed here, if view should be updated } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you I took into consideration what I wrote. I also modified my code as written in my answer. It seems to be working now

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick answer Blechdose it helped a lot.

For the naming convention: It is not for my work, just a hobby project, so no issue changing in the way you proposed it.

I realized I did not applied INotifyPropertyChanged correctly. So, I rewrote it, than after a little bit of search I realized if I used FodyPropertyChanged NuGet package to weave my assembly my code could be a tad cleaner.

I also changed my arrayLists to ObservableCollections. ( I only used arrayList cause as being new to programming it seemed like a good fit)

```
    class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

    public static ObservableCollection<string> SystemList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    public static ObservableCollection<string> TitleList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    public static ObservableCollection<string> RevisionList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    public static ObservableCollection<DocumentModel> DocumentList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<DocumentModel>();
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    public static string SystemFilter { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
```

And as for BaseViewModel I kept:

```
    public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The event that is fired when any child poperty changes its value
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

And I installed Fody PropertyChanged so I do not have to set everytime something like this:

```
private string mTest;
    public string Test
    {
        get
        {
            return mTest;
        }

        set
        {
            if (mTest == value)
                return;
            mTest = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Test)));
        }

    }
```

Thanks for the feedback. It works correctly now. (So far at least :))

Comment: you can remove the static keyword. it is not needed here.